# Meteor not outputting MongoDB query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

**main.html:**

```
{{#each getRequests}}
    <li><a href="/req/{{_id}}">{{_id}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

**main.js**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe('getRequests',{fbID : Meteor.user().services.facebook.id});
}
```

**publications.js**

```
Meteor.publish('getRequests', function(args) {
    return data.find({"potentialUsers.user_id" : args.fbID});
});
```

I'm stuck trying to get the main.html to display the IDs from the database. The user's ID can be in multiple documents in the "data" table, nested within data.potentialUsers.user_id. What I don't understand is that when I put the query into `meteor mongo` (in the command line) it executes successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly new to meteor myself, but reading through the docs I see these issues.

Subscribe makes the documents available to the client from the publication. You still need to write a function to deliver them to the html.

main.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe('getRequests',{fbID : Meteor.user().services.facebook.id});

    Template.body.helpers({
        getRequests: function(){
           return data.find() // since you want everything the publication has.
        }
    })

}
```

Then in your html:

```
{{#each getRequests}}
    <li><a href="/req/{{_id}}">{{_id}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: That was it! Didn't realize you had to redefine the function. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: It's bad practice to forward all the user information to the browser. Facebook tokens etc... can be used to impersonate someone.